Cat5 Cable to Power Ring Doorbell
I am replacing an On-Q intercom with a hardwired ring doorbell. The intercom had a Cat5 line coming to it. I'd like to use the basic Ring Doorbell (B08CKHPP52) ... the one with two terminals on the back.
Can I simply use the cat5 wires to run the doorbell? Are there specific ones I should use?

What does the Ring Doorbell instructions say?

Yes if your existing doorbell is a typical one powered by a 24V transformer, that Ring is meant to just take power from the same transformer using the same wires.
Cat5 cable is usually 24AWG and the Ring uses 0.5A.   It's not ideal, larger wire would be better.  But it will probably work.  If the distance from the transformer to the Ring is typical for a home, IE, 50 ft or less, it ought to be fine but you won't know til you test it.   If there's 100+ ft of wire it might not work but again .. you can only try.   You can use any wires.  They are paired by color, so use a matched pair.
If the voltage drop at the Ring is too much and it doesn't work, you can try paralleling the wires in the Cat5 cable. That means: there are 8 wires in the cable.  Use four of them (any four) from one side of the transformer to the Ring, and the other four for the other side.  Note the comment suggesting to do this by default without even trying one wire alone regardless of length.  It's a good idea: the four white wires with colored stripes for one side and the four colored wires with white stripes for the other.

The trivial way to do it better - strip all 8 wires in the cable, twist togeter all of the "white plus a color" ones and all the solid colored ones. This not being line voltage, paralleling conductors is not a problem, and this way it will make use of the twisted pairs being twisted. As opposed to ignoring the pairs and just twisting "any" together.

@Ecnerwal Are you saying to parallel by default without even attempting single-wire installation even if that is how the old doorbell was done?   I think I agree with that.  It's not hard, and only upside.  I definitely agree with the color scheme.

For a two-wire bell, using undersized 4-pair wire - yes, parallel by default.

Wrong, utterly wrong, @Thomas

@Thomas really, to say that's wrong is being kind.  There are several PoE standards and none of them is remotely as you describe.   Can you tell us how you "jam" a twisted insulated pair of wires into a doorbell transformer?

This is not a POE device. It's a two-wire that expects twisted pairs. You are deeply confused. And advocating ignoring the twisted pairs as you apprently lack the visual acuity to tell the difference between a solid and striped wires in a pair.

Thanks everyone. Gonna give it a try this weekend. Will report back
